# Google Analytics - Status: Tracking Not Installed

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I made a very simple page to test and implement a platform which allows a user to connect to google analytics and process their data.

The initial test page is:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B3AOJZL6qwZTcVpKWmYtbldXV1U/index.html

As you can see, the page is hosted in a public gdrive folder, is that a problem? or it should work ok?

Currently the realtime api reporting is working correctly.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

This is the tracking code i put on the head:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-51755420-2', 'googledrive.com');
        ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

And this is the output from the GA Debugger

```
    Initializing Google Analytics. analytics_debug.js:9
    Running command: ga(create, UA-51755420-2, googledrive.com) analytics_debug.js:9
    Creating new tracker: t0 analytics_debug.js:9
    Running command: ga(require, displayfeatures) analytics_debug.js:9
    Set called on unknown field: "dcLoaded". analytics_debug.js:9
    Plugin "displayfeatures" intialized on tracker "t0". analytics_debug.js:9
    Running command: ga(send, pageview) analytics_debug.js:9
    Setting throttling cookie: "_dc" analytics_debug.js:9

    Sent beacon:
    v=1&_v=j22d&a=1817669302&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogledrive.com%2Fhost%2F0B3AOJZL6qwZTcVpKWmYtbldXV1U%2Findex.html&ul=es&de=ISO-8859-1&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=1600x211&je=1&fl=13.0%20r0&_u=MCCAgAQ~&jid=1236507930&cid=1216002561.1402365868&tid=UA-51755420-2&z=2074969389

     analytics_debug.js:9
    _j1              (&jid) 1236507930 analytics_debug.js:9
    adSenseId        (&a)   1817669302 analytics_debug.js:9
    apiVersion       (&v)   1 analytics_debug.js:9
    clientId         (&cid) 1216002561.1402365868 analytics_debug.js:9
    encoding         (&de)  ISO-8859-1 analytics_debug.js:9
    flashVersion     (&fl)  13.0 r0 analytics_debug.js:9
    hitType          (&t)   pageview analytics_debug.js:9
    javaEnabled      (&je)  1 analytics_debug.js:9
    language         (&ul)  es analytics_debug.js:9
    location         (&dl)  https://googledrive.com/host/0B3AOJZL6qwZTcVpKWmYtbldXV1U/index.html analytics_debug.js:9
    screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit analytics_debug.js:9
    screenResolution (&sr)  1600x900 analytics_debug.js:9
    trackingId       (&tid) UA-51755420-2 analytics_debug.js:9
    viewportSize     (&vp)  1600x211 analytics_debug.js:9

    Sent beacon:
    https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/collect?t=dc&aip=1&v=1&_v=j22d&tid=UA-51755420-2&cid=1216002561.1402365868&jid=1236507930&_u=MCCAgAQ~&z=1404606034

     analytics_debug.js:9
    apiVersion (&v)   1 analytics_debug.js:9
    trackingId (&tid) UA-51755420-2 analytics_debug.js:9
    clientId   (&cid) 1216002561.1402365868 analytics_debug.js:9
    _j1        (&jid) 1236507930 analytics_debug.js:9
```

Comment: obviously not going to work without your sitemaster code block in there, pretty sure you have to copy some type of code from your google dashboard

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It started working without changing anything :) I was worried about the googledrive domain but there was no problem there.

Comment: the tracking code was not there when i looked at it.. maybe u had page cashes

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What does the Google Analytics tracking code have to do with using the Api to access data.  Is this an app script you have running to request data?

Comment: yes, it is an app script in php accessing the API. But to implement it correctly i wanted a page to test my implementation. The problem was that i wasn't being able to track any data with that page.